# How to bounce ball in paddle game on another shape using collisions?

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to get the ball to bounce on the platform, but the collision can't be detected? How can we detect collision or make it bounce from the platform? We have made the ball and its gravity. The ball can also bounce from the sides of the canvas, and made the platform move from keyboard arrow keys.

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time
import math
import tkinter

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 1000

tk=Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=1200, height=900)

tk.title("Brick Breaker")

platform = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 40, 250, 30, fill ="black")
def leftKey(event):
    canvas.move(platform, -40, 0)
    pass
def rightKey(event):
    canvas.move(platform, 40, 0)
    pass
tk.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
tk.bind('<Right>', rightKey)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
#alligns the platform
left = 0
for x in range(0,18):
        canvas.move(1, 40, 40)
        tk.update()

ball = canvas.create_oval(5, 5, 30, 30, fill ="black")
xspeed = 0.1   #gravity
yspeed = 0.4
while True:
        canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(ball)
        if pos[3] >= 900 or pos[1] <= 0: # y range
            yspeed = -yspeed
        if pos[2] >=  1200 or pos[0] <= 0: # x range
            xspeed = -xspeed
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.00000001) #speed

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: BTW: you don't need `pass`. Put all functions before `tk=Tk()` to make code more readable. You could use `after(miliseconds, function_name)` instead of `while True` and `sleep()` - now you don't need `mainloop()` because you never leave `while True`. Canvas has function to check overlaping two elements - so you can use it to check collision.

Comment: [Canvas.find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `canvas.find_overlapping(*ball_pos)` to check if ball overlaps other objects. It returns IDs of all objects in rectangle `ball_pos` - event ball - so it is never empty.

It is not ideal because it doesn't check if ball collide below/above/left/right so you don't know how to change direction.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 1000

# --- functions ---

# for smooth move of platform

def left_press(event):
    global platform_left
    platform_left = True

def left_release(event):
    global platform_left
    platform_left = False

def right_press(event):
    global platform_right
    platform_right = True

def right_release(event):
    global platform_right
    platform_right = False


def eventloop():
    global xspeed
    global yspeed

    # move ball
    canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
    ball_pos = canvas.coords(ball)

    # move platform
    if platform_left:
        # move
        canvas.move(platform, -20, 0)
        platform_pos = canvas.coords(platform)
        # check if not leave canvas
        if platform_pos[0] < 0:
            # move back
            canvas.move(platform, 0-platform_pos[0], 0)
    if platform_right:
        # move
        canvas.move(platform, 20, 0)
        # check if not leave canvas
        platform_pos = canvas.coords(platform)
        if platform_pos[2] > 1200:
            # move back
            canvas.move(platform, -(platform_pos[2]-1200), 0)

    # - collisions -

    # check collision with border

    if ball_pos[3] >= 900 or ball_pos[1] <= 0: # y range
        yspeed = -yspeed
    if ball_pos[2] >= 1200 or ball_pos[0] <= 0: # x range
        xspeed = -xspeed

    # check collisions with objects 

    collide = canvas.find_overlapping(*ball_pos)

    if platform in collide:
        yspeed = -yspeed

    remove = []

    # check collision with bricks
    for brick in bricks:
        if brick in collide:
            remove.append(brick)
            yspeed = -yspeed

    # remove bricks
    for brick in remove:
        bricks.remove(brick)
        canvas.delete(brick)

    root.after(10, eventloop)

# --- main ---

# - init -

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Brick Breaker")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1200, height=900)
canvas.pack()

# - objects -

ball = canvas.create_oval(5, 5, 30, 30, fill="black")
xspeed = 1 # gravity
yspeed = 4

platform = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 40, 250, 30, fill="black")
platform_left = False
platform_right = False
root.bind('<Left>', left_press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Left>', left_release)
root.bind('<Right>', right_press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Right>', right_release)

bricks = []

for i in range(10):
    x = i*100
    y = 700
    brick = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+50, y+30, fill="red")
    bricks.append(brick)

# - mainloop -

root.after(100, eventloop)
root.mainloop()
```

**BTW:** to control speed better change `xspeed`, `yspeed` instead of `after()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, how do you change the location of the platform?

Comment: after pressing left/right arrow it sets  `platform_left = True` or `platform_rigth = True`. And `eventloop` checks it and executes `canvas.move(platform, dx, dy)`