# How do you update a scoreboard using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a brick breaker game using tkinter, but cannot figure out how to update the scoreboard. I do not get any error messages. The only problem is that the scoreboard stays at zero throughout the game. It should add 10 points each time a block is hit. Any suggestions would be amazing.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, score, block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.block1 = block1
        self.block2 = block2
        self.block3 = block3
        self.block4 = block4
        self.block5 = block5
        self.score = score
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3 
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
        if self.hit_block(pos) == True:
            self.y = +3
        if self.hit_block == True:
            self.scoreboard = self.score_board + self.add_score



    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def hit_block(self,pos):
        block1_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block1.id)
        if block1_pos and (pos[2] >= block1_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block1_pos[2]):
            if block1_pos and(pos[3] >= block1_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block1_pos[3]):
                self.canvas.delete(self.block1.id)
                return True

        block2_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block2.id)
        if block2_pos and (pos[2] >= block2_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block2_pos[2]):
            if block2_pos and(pos[3] >= block2_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block2_pos[3]):
                self.canvas.delete(self.block2.id)

                return True

        block3_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block3.id)
        if block3_pos and (pos[2] >= block3_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block3_pos[2]):
            if block3_pos and(pos[3] >= block3_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block3_pos[3]):
                self.canvas.delete(self.block3.id)

                return True

        block4_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block4.id)
        if block4_pos and (pos[2] >= block4_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block4_pos[2]):
            if block4_pos and(pos[3] >= block4_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block4_pos[3]):
                self.canvas.delete(self.block4.id)

                return True

        block5_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block5.id)
        if block5_pos and (pos[2] >= block5_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block5_pos[2]):
            if block5_pos and(pos[3] >= block5_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block5_pos[3]):
                self.canvas.delete(self.block5.id)

                return True
        return False



class Score:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.add_score = 10
        self.scoreboard = 0
        self.id = canvas.create_text(50,25, text='Your score = %s' %(self.scoreboard))

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0




class Block:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 50, self.y + 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)




block1 = Block(canvas, 50, 25, 'orange')
block2 = Block(canvas, 90, 25, 'yellow')
block3 = Block(canvas, 130, 25, 'green')
block4 = Block(canvas, 170, 25, 'blue')
block5 = Block(canvas, 210, 25, 'violet')
score = Score(canvas)
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, score, block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, 'red')



while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: You should not really make classes if they only have __init__ except if you're inheriting (which you're not).

Comment: you should keep blocks on list `block[0]`, `block[1]`, etc. and use `for` loop to check collision in `hit_paddle`. Your code will be much shorter and easier to change.

Comment: `canvas` has [find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) which you could use to easily check collision with blocks.

Comment: see `brick breaker` with `find_overlapping`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41587019/1832058

Comment: Also note that  "canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text='Your score = %s' % (self.scoreboard))" should be executed every time score.scoreboard changes in value. You can do this with the @property decorator easily OR you can write a method for SetScore or IncScore. You're choice.

Comment: @Frogboxe `@property` or `SetScore` could be good but `tkinter` has `IntVar` and `trace()` for this :)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I will try it out :)

Comment: Ah, then go with that then OP. I don't use tkinter anymore and I was only ever a n00b in it anyway... Been using a wrapper I wrote for pygame for ages now

Answer (score 2):

After you change `self.scoreboard` you have to replace text manually

```
 canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text='Your score = %s' % (self.scoreboard))
```

effbot.org: [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

---

BTW: If you use `IntVar()` to keep score then you could use `trace('w', callback)` to assign function `callback` to this `IntVar()` which could change this text on canvas everytime you change value in this `IntVar()`

effbot.org: [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)